# How do you implement shortcode using PHP and wordpress using object-oriented programming?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to build a plugin using PHP OOP, and I cannot seem to get this 1st step working. Is there a problem with this code? When I put the shortcode [rsb-archive] into a wordpress page, all it doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
class RSB_Archive {
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_shortcode('rsb-archive', array($this, 'shortcode'));
    }

    public function shortcode()
    {
           // Contents of this function will execute when the blogger
          // uses the [rsb-archive] shortcode.

          echo "print this code";



    }
}
```

That does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Additionally, does anyone have any insight on how to debug code using PHP. I am just beginning to learn how to use it.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you assigning the widget instance that executes this

Comment: The shortcode is being placed into a wordpress page, however, I don't really understand your question.

Comment: And you're just calling `$RSB_Archive = new RSB_Archive;`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Well you can't just put this code anywhere and hope that it executes, you must instantiate this class to fire off the constructor function. [Take this for example](http://ideone.com/WtVDz5)

Comment: Ah, ok. Could you point me in the right direction to learn how and why I might instantiate a class? super beginner here, thanks!

Comment: Ok cool, thanks, your example is working well! I have had trouble figuring out what that "new" does?

Comment: however, your code makes the echo happen twice above the header?? seen here: <http://www.robotspacebrain.com/archive-coding/> why is that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48826/discussion-between-rsb-and-ohgodwhy)

Answer (score 4):

You have to create an instance of the widget object first.

like so;

```
<?php

class RSB_Archive {

    public function __construct() {
       // don't call add_shortcode here
       // actually, I worked with wordpress last year and
       // i think this is a good place to call add_shortcode 
       // (and all other filters) now...
    }

    public function shortcode() {
        echo 'doTheDoo';
    }
}

$myWidged = new RSB_Archive();

add_shortcode('my-code', array($myWidget, 'shortcode'));

?>
```

[This has been answered more thoroughly](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61437/php-error-with-shortcode-handler-from-a-class)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to create the instance of the class RSB_Archive. 
the codes inside the constructor runs while create the object.

```
class RSB_Archive {

public function __construct()
{
    add_shortcode('rsb-archive', array($this, 'shortcode'));
}

public function shortcode()
{
       // Contents of this function will execute when the blogger
      // uses the [rsb-archive] shortcode.

      echo "print this code";



   }
}

$obj = new RSB_Archive();
```